# Generate a regular graph

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, open-ended-function, binary-matrix

<sub>Inspired by [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/261869/71549) Mathematica.SE post</sub>

Given two positive integers \$n, k\$ with \$n > k \ge 1\$, output a binary \$n\times n\$ matrix such that every row and column contains exactly \$k\$ 1s, and the leading diagonal is all zero. This is the adjacency matrix of a [regular graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph).

You may output any valid matrix, and it does not have to be deterministic. You may output in any [reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/66833), including a flat \$n^2\$ list, or a nested list, etc.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
n, k -> output
2, 1 -> [[0, 1], [1, 0]]
5, 3 -> [[0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
3, 1 -> [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]
5, 1 -> [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
6, 2 -> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
7, 6 -> [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: A random regular graph would be a nice challenge.

Comment: @graffe I considered that, but I'm not a big fan of "Generate a random X" challenges

Comment: I guess more specifically this is the adjacency matrix of a regular *directed* graph. Otherwise it would have to be symmetric, and there would be no solution for inputs like n=5, k=3.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 5 bytes

```
Ḷṙ`U<
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLhuLbhuZlgVTwiLCIiLCIiLFsiNSIsIjMiXV0=)

-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan

```
Ḷṙ`U<    Main Link; take n, k
Ḷ        [0, 1, 2, ..., n - 1]
  `      Apply with ^ on the left and right:
 ṙ       Rotate left; [[0, 1, 2, ..., n - 1], [1, 2, 3, ..., n - 1, 0], [2, 3, 4, ..., n - 1, 0, 1], ...]
   U     Reverse each; [[n - 1, n - 2, ..., 1, 0], [0, n - 1, n - 2, ..., 2, 1], [1, 0, n - 1, ..., 3, 2], ...]
    <    Is this less than k? [[0, ..., 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, ..., 1, 1], ...]
                                       ^-- k --^
```

Comment: Here's a six that is the same idea ``ḶṙⱮ`U<``.

Comment: @JonathanAllan oh, that's... a lot clever than all of the alternate ideas I came up with. Also, rotate can take a list on the right fine without needing the each in this case.

Comment: Nice, forgot it would vectorise!

Answer (score 5):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 33 bytes

```
f(n,k)=matrix(n,,i,j,(i-j-1)%n<k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYjNCsIwDIBfJQyEBpLDOpwHdS8Seshlkk1LKDvMp6@rHjx9P67F@OG1ziHTiveXbsX2w8looWC8cI@nfFuxqvvzHRR4Ai@Wt0M7njq8/tLDHFT6RKASEyKBSCRoQ84EQ@Pw7y9Hgth4IRhTwvoB)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2), 45 bytes

Saved 15 bytes thanks to [loopy walt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107561/loopy-walt)! (Using the flat list output option.)

```python
lambda n,k:[(i/n+~i)%n<k for i in range(n*n)]
```

An unnamed function accepting `n` and `k` that returns a list of booleans

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RToNAEEXf/Yr7YpjFkUYaa0LaL8GGrIG2K2Ugyxoxpv113EVSui93Z25y5nQ/7tRKOh4rVzTaWTNgh/fxrJuPUkO4znIyK3m6GvUo2xqH1sLACKyWY0USi9qPYSmMOuyJUsaLYtArYx1yvcxTbhhpyDfGRqnsAf511ohD9HvJosTTvAlRICo11bbqv87Omy2a//XUhvO2/S6MlNVw5zaz7/iIks/WCDW6o95ZRvj4hucLucQLKIPEz9fbvFezzMyKxj8)**

Comment: As we are allowed a flat list for output: 46 https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY39XISc5NSEhXydLKtojUy9fXztOsyNVXzbLIV0vKLFDIVMvMUihLz0lM18rTyNGOhuupAckAtINnoaCMdw1idaFMdYyBpDGWDSDMdIyBprmMWG2vFpQAEBUWZeSUaSjF5SjpAzZpgMZBJOSBzqjILNLTytKJzEws0gMp00jRAajRjNSF6EfpzNCGuWLAAQgMA

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 50 bytes

*Fixed version now using [Jonathan Allan's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240917/58563)*
*Thanks to @emanresuA for spotting some dead code (-2 bytes)*

Expects `(n)(k)`, returns a flat array of Boolean values.

```javascript
n=>k=>[...Array(n*n)].map((_,x)=>(x+~(x/n)+n)%n<k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcxBCsIwFEXRufsQ3rP6RYt2YgKuQ0RCbUVbf0oqEiduPXaqxenhcm/u6foyXLvHQv25SrVJamxj7EFE9iG4F3SmPMrddcBpHmksYvZGXCoz5VR3DVPptfdtJa2/oMaaWJGTb9wQ@QjzP@UYtxy2v1hwcKYP) (raw output)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc7BboJAEAbgO0/xXxpmyrpNNeoBl6QHn4JuyIaCIjprwBga0746paSY9tDTfPNnJvkP7uravKnOl5n4t6IvTS8mqU2Saq1fmsa9kzwKW31yZ6JMdWwS6qJP6p6EI@EH2dTcx2kApJgrPMOq0UuFxeTF3/zulcJ88lphBRvYQJe@2bp8T5SKQm0ZJsFtuHEwKEmYao6HNffS@mOhj35Hv8r@VM2@v/6JI6fbfVVeiFkffCUUIrzzVUJGhHHGwQf3Xw) (with post-processing)

Comment: Am I missing something, or is the assignment to `y` unnecessary?

Comment: @emanresuA Good catch! That was probably left from a previous version.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 6 bytes

```
Ḷ_þ%Ɗ<
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLhuLZfw74lxoo8IiwiIiwiIixbIjUiLCIzIl1d)

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.matrices`, <sup><s>64</s></sup> 60 bytes

```
[ dupd dupd '[ - 1 - _ rem _ < 1 0 ? ] <matrix-by-indices> ]
```

The `<matrix-by-indices>` word postdates build 1525 (the one TIO uses), so here's a screenshot of running this in Factor's REPL:

[image]

This is a port of @alephalpha's [Pari/GP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240885/97916). `<matrix-by-indices>` is a combinator with stack effect `( ... m n quot: ( ... i j -- ... elt ) -- ... matrix )`. In other words, it lets you generate an `m`x`n` matrix but leaves the indices of each element (`i`, `j`) on top of the stack while you do so.

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
rxm<k(Å_╪
```

Outputs all rows concatenated to the stack.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7@oItcmW@Nwa/yjqav@/zdSMOQyVTDmMgbThlxmCkZc5gpmAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
r          # Push a list in the range [0, first (implicit) input n)
 x         # Reverse it to range (n,0]
  m        # Map over each integer:
   <       #  Check if it's larger than the second (implicit) input k
    k      # Push the first input n again
     (     # Decrease it by 1
      Å    # Loop that many times,
           # using the following 2 characters as inner code-block:
       _   #  Duplicate the top list
        ╪  #  Rotate the items in the list once towards the right
           # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Apl

**67 bytes**

`{{(⍴⍵)⍴{⍵[?⍨≢⍵]}∊⍵}⍣{((∧/2=/+/,+⌿)⍺)∧∧/~1 1⍉⍺}⍵ ⍵⍴⍺(⍺-⍵)/1 0}`

incredebly ineffecent ,might be needlessly long

explantion

`{{(⍴⍵)⍴{⍵[?⍨≢⍵]}∊⍵}` shuffles array randomly untill

`{∧/~1 1⍉⍺}`digonal is all 0s

`{((∧/2=/+/,+⌿)⍺)}` and  sum of all the rows and column is the same

`{⍵ ⍵⍴⍺(⍺-⍵)/1 0}` makes a n×n matrix of right argument with required 0s and 1s

Comment: Bogosort style approach, very interesting

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>49</s> <s>40</s> 38 bytes

*Edit: -9 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
function(n,k)outer(1:n-1,1:n,`-`)%%n<k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPJ1szv7QktUjD0CpP11AHSOok6CZoqqrm2WT/107TMNEx1OQC00ZQ2ljzPwA)

Returns a matrix with values `TRUE`/`FALSE` (which evaluate to `1`/`0` in [R](https://www.r-project.org/)).  Add [+3 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPJ1tTWyO/tCS1SMPQKk/XUAdI6iToJmiqqubZZGv@T9Mw0THU5AJRRhDKWPM/AA) to output as a matrix with `1`s and `0`s directly.

---

Or my very lazy first attempt:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 93 bytes

```r
function(n,k,`?`=rowSums){while(any(c(?(m=matrix(sample(1:0,n^2,T),n)),?t(m))-k,diag(m)))0;m}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BDoIwEADvvmQ3WRNAT5qmj5Cz0iCWBnchSwkS4turntTbzFxGkzb@4tUNrUm3SeoYegGhjipbGe3n08QjrnMb7g04WaAGC2zYRQ0PGB0P754fMpJzQSWSIJKNwIjbjq7B@Q9iduTndwR7ynHzq8W/7jC9AA)

Extremely inefficient (and often times-out on TIO even for the n≥5 test-cases), but will eventually (= nonzero probability) deliver the right answer each time.

Samples random matrices of `0`, `1` until a solution is found that satisfies the rowSums, colSums & diag conditions.

Comment: [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPJ1tTWyO/tCS1SMPQKk/XUCfPyhBIJmgnaKqq5tlka/5P0zDRMdTkAlFGEMpY8z8A) golfing your `sapply` variant to use `outer` instead.

Comment: @Giuseppe - Thanks a lot.  That also beats all my current attempts using n x n+1 matrices, which I will now trash...

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＥθ⮌⭆θ‹﹪⁺ιλθη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oLmZ8B5AcUZeaVaPgmFmgU6igEpZalFhWnagSXAEXToYI@qcXFGr75KaU5@RoBOaXFGpk6CjmaOgqFQJyhCQLW//@bKhj/1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                  First input `n` as a number
  Ｎη                Second input `k` as a number
     θ              First input
    Ｅ               Map over implicit range
        θ           First input
       ⭆            Map over implicit range and join
            ι       Row index
           ⁺        Plus
             λ      Column index
          ﹪         Modulo
              θ     First input
         ‹          Is less than
               η    Second input
      ⮌             Reversed
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 38 bytes

```
\d+
$*0
(0+) \1
$.1$*
.
$'$`$&¶
O$^`.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZFm0tFy4BLw0BbUyHGkEtFz1BFi0uPS0VdJUFF7dA2Ln@VuAQ97f//jRQMuUwVjLmMwbQhlxkQmyuYAQA) Link includes test cases. Output includes trailing newlines. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*0
```

Convert both inputs to strings of `0`s.

```
(0+) \1
$.1$*
```

Subtract `k` from `n` and convert it to a string of `1`s, so there are now `n-k` `0`s and `k` `1`s.

```
.
$'$`$&¶
```

Generate the cyclic permutations of that string in reverse order.

```
O$^`.+
```

Reverse the permutations into the desired order. (Normally the `$` needs another line to specify the sort key but this is an edge case where it's not needed.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 41 bytes

```
IdentityMatrix@#~RotateLeft~n~Sum~{n,#2}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zMlNa8ks6TSN7GkKLPCQbkuKL8ksSTVJzWtpC6vLrg0t646T0fZqFbtf0BRZl5JdFq0kY5hbCwXjGeqY4zEM0aTQ@aZ6Rgh8cx1zGJj/wMA)

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pyi/JLEk1Sc1rSTaMyU1rySzpNI3saQos8JBWSe2Lrg0t65aR9moVu1/QFFmXkl0WrSRjmFsLBeMZ6pjjMQzRpND5pnpGCHxzHXMYmP/AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 49 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a.times.map{|c|([0]*(a-b)+[1]*b).rotate c}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6k6Ua8kMze1WC83saC6JrlGI9ogVksjUTdJUzvaMFYrSVOvKL8ksSRVIbm29n@BQlq0qY5x7H8A)

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, <s>23</s> 21 bytes

Prompts for k followed by n. Index origin = 0

```
(⌽⍳n)⌽(n,n)⍴(n←⎕)↑⎕⍴1
```

[Try it online!Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tv8ajnr2PejfnaQJpjTwdIN27RSMPKA9Up/mobSKQAooY/gcq5vqfxmXIZcSlrqDOlcZlzGUKZRkC2TAWTMyIywzKMuMy5wIA)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
{↑(-⍳⍵)⌽¨⊂⍵↑⍺⍴1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR20QN3Ue9mx/1btV81LP30IpHXU1ANlD4Ue@uR71bDGv/pz1qm/Cot@9R31RP/0ddzYfWG4Nk@6YGBzkDyRAPz@D/afqHVihoGCuYaipomCmYA0lDIBsA)

Generates a fixed pattern by rotating each row by its index.

---

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 41 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
{{⍵[?⍨≢⍵]}⍤1⍣{(~1 1⍉⍺)∧.=≢∪+⌿⍺}↑⍵/⊂⍵↑⍺/1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v7r6Ue/WaPtHvSsedS4CMmNrH/UuMXzUu7hao85QAcjofNS7S/NRx3I9W5CCjlXaj3r2A4VqH7VNBCrXf9TVBKTAnF36hrX/0x61TXjU2/eob6qn/6Ou5kPrjUFyfVODg5yBZIiHZ/D/NP1DKxQ0jBVMNRU0TMCkoYKJJgA)

Shuffles each row until the conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
ɾṘ≥:(…ǔ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwiyb7huZjiiaU6KOKApseUIiwiIiwiNVxuMyJd)

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 49 bytes

```
;=xE P;=yE P;=i~1W>^x 2=i+1iO+0>y%+x%--/i x iTx x
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PXhFIFA7PXlFIFA7PWl+MVc+XnggMj1pKzFpTyswPnklK3glLS0vaSB4IGlUeCB4IiwiNVxyXG4zIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 223 bytes:

```py
from itertools import*
def f(n,k,c=[]):
 if len(c)==n:yield c
 else:
  for i in product(*[{0,not c or(i!=len(c)and sum([*zip(*c)][i])<k)}for i in range(n)]):
   if sum(i)==k:yield from f(n,k,c+[i])
g=lambda n,k:next(f(n,k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7LboMwEEX3fMV056FetEFNI1R/CWJB/aAjzNgyjpSk6rdToGmFujxzde@ZeM0fgatTTPPsUhiBsk05BD8BjTGkXBbGOnCC5SC1alqsCyAH3rLQqBTXV7LegC7A@skuIbiQgIAYYgrmrLMom88nySGDhpAEPaifcscGpvMomvJGUZQa24ZafBvw628hddxbwbhZYfWuBVq8w927/Xz/7nHtF73y3fhuOlhuNdtLFluMOMdEnEUvDvIZsfilF1ntqPqX7ekoDzt6lcdl8xs)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LR@Dv=Á
```

Pretty similar approach as [my MathGolf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240893/52210).
Outputs all rows-lists on a separated line.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fJ8jBpcz2cOP//6ZcxgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WGeSSoOSZV1BaUmylkGd7eL@OQjaQVNLhUvIvLQEKWyko6ST89wlycCmzPdz4v/bQNvv/0dFGOoaxOtGmOsZA0hjKBpFmOkZA0lzHLDYWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
L        # Push a list in the range [1, first (implicit) input n]
 R       # Reverse it to [n,1]
  @      # Check for each value if the second (implicit) input k >= the value
   D     # Duplicate this list
    v    # Pop and loop its size amount of times:
     =   #  Print the list with trailing newline (without popping)
      Á  #  Rotate its items once towards the right
```

Answer (score 1):

## brev, 82

```
(lambda(n k)((over(with i((over(if(or(= i it)(> i k))0 1))x)))(make'()n(iota n))))
```

Comment: Ah no this has a bug, I just realized. Some rows will have one 1 too many.